# how to check which view in storyboard are showing

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uistoryboard

i will like to know which storyboard view are being showed.

```
 [self setLeftPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menuListViewController"]];
    [self setCenterPanel:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavCenterController"]];
    [self setRightPanel:[self.storyboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"designView"]];
```

i will like to check if "NavCenterController" are shown, disable something

any comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, in order to check whether any view is being shown, you should check its `window` property.
For a view controller you would do the following:

```
if(self.view.window)
    // the view controller is being shown, do something
else
    // the view controller is not being shown
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.

i wanna check the view controller name in storyboard which i instantiated

Comment: in that case you could first instantiate it like NavCenterController* nav = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"identifier"], then set it as the centralPanel and finally control its window property, with nav.view.window. Is that what you need?